# Sampling frequency of voice and audio

Tags: matlab

I read somewhere that the signal of speech has a bandwidth from 300 - 3400 Hz(Why), and audio files have a bandwidth from 50 Hz to 50000 HZ(Why).

Could someone help me , why are those constant sampling frequencies ?

Comment: full bandwidth audio is generally thought to be from 20 Hz to 20 kHz.  not 50.  this is why the sampling rate of good-quality audio must exceed 40000 samples per second.  speech doesn't require as high sampling rate (8000 samples per second is what telephony uses) because it doesn't have the bandwidth of the full audio spectrum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the human hearing which defines associated bandwidths. Then the sampling frequency will be chosen to be larger than twice the bandwidth for satisfying the sampling theory and still as small as possible to reduce processing costs.

Human hearing for the general sound signals is accepted to be between 20 Hz and 20 kHz. The limits depending on individual, age, gender etc.

Note that various mechanical devices, acoustical instruments or alike can produce sound waves that are well in excess of 20 kHz upper limit and include ultrasound, however, an ordinary human will not be able to hear that, that's why the upper limit is taken to be 20 kHz.

For speech used in old analog communication (telephony audio) network, the intention was to find the minimum intelligible bandwidth to reduce the technical complexity and economic cost of building that network. This bandwidth is found to be within 300-3000 Hz. However as technology improved and other means of speech communication emerged, higher bandwidth audio was also used for better quality transmission. Digital codecs, radio broadcast etc. can use 8 kHz, 16 kHz etc. bandwidths too.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between a speech signal where what is said can be reasonably comprehended, a speech signal that sounds good, and speech signal that sounds so realistic that the speaker might be there.  300 to 3400 Hz is for a tolerable level of communication quality (people get used to it), 20 Hz to 20 or 40 kHz is for higher levels of realism.  Recording well above 20 kHz is usually done, not to reproduce ultrasonic spectra, but for a much flatter frequency and phase response (less distortion) around the very top of the audible frequency range.

Some types of human vocalizations might actually produce ultrasonics (well above 20 kHz), but since humans can't hear audio spectra at those high frequencies, they are usually filtered out before recording.  But perhaps bats (certain dog breeds, etc.) would react differently, given a recording and reproduction at a higher sampling rate.